# friendly url onChange()

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Im populating a form selected options via a mysql query.

The result looks something like this :

```
<form method="get" action="">

  <select name="recordlabel" onChange="submit()">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1">COLUMBIA</option>
    <option value="2">SONY</option>
    <option value="3">EMI</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

When I select an option, it automatically submits the form and looks like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/?recordlabel=3
```

What i want is to use friendly url and should look like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/recordlabel/emi.3

http://www.mysite.com/recordlabel/columbia.1
```

Now, i know that i need to use mode_rewrite... that i have no problemo and looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/recordlabel/.*\.([0-9]+)$ /mysite.com?recordlalel=$1 [L]
```

The part that i don't get is how do i format the string so it looks like a friendly url onChange() How do i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use javascript to submit your form instead of relying on native submit.

If you're using jQuery, you can do this (untested):

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $(this).serialize();
  $.get('/recordlabel/'+formData.recordLabel', function(data){
   //do something with response data.
  });
});
```

Comment: not if you want to use pretty urls...but I'm not sure why you care what url a form posts to. Pretty URLs are usually only used in place of static paths like pages.

Comment: this doesnt work... $('.target').change(function()... The on change event doesnt send a friendly url to the server

Comment: sorry, i missed the onchange event. try `$("select").change()`